# SQL server - Check for object existence in SP before creation

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, user-defined-functions

Why following SP would not generate error at time of creation or alteration? 
I used a scalar function `[dbo.fn_General_GetCurrentTime()]` in following SP which does not exist in database 'AdventureWorks2014'.

I am confused whether it should give the error or not.
Is there any way that we can force it to check the object existence?

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Zee_Test]
    @ID   int
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @DateC DateTime

    Set @DateC = dbo.fn_General_GetCurrentTime() --this function is not exists in database
END

GO
```

Comment: People have been asking for decades for some way to disable Deferred Name Resolution, no sign of anything being implemented any time soon. It's a "feature".

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an object exists in your DB using metadata tables. For stored procedures and functions you can use table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` :

```
--check if a stored procedure exists
if exists (SELECT 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_TYPE ='PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA='yourSpSchema' and ROUTINE_NAME='yourSpName')
    begin
        --the stored procedure exists 
    end
else 
    begin
        --the stored procedure does not exist
    end

--check if a function exists
if exists (SELECT 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_TYPE ='FUNCTION' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA='yourFxSchema' and ROUTINE_NAME='yourFxName')
    begin
        --the function exists 
    end
else 
    begin
        --the function does not exist
    end
```